# Issue with Recursion - Hoping to get advice specific to my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recursion, tail-recursion

I tried asking advice related to this issue in the past and I was told that the root of the problem is "tail recursion". People directed me to tangentially related posts but I've had trouble applying the advice in those posts to my code.

Could someone please explain specific modifications that I can make to my code to fix the recursion issue I'm having (detailed below)? I've spent hours trying to fix this and have gotten nowhere (noob here...).

So, some background on my code:

**This generates 2 distinct random numbers between 2 & 20:**

```
function GenerateRandomNumber1to20No1() {
    var min = 2, max = 20;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;   
    return random;

}

 var GenerateRandomNumber1to20No1 = GenerateRandomNumber1to20No1(); 
$('.GenerateRandomNumber1to20No1').html(GenerateRandomNumber1to20No1);

 function GenerateRandomNumber1to20No2() {
    var min = 2, max = 20;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;   
  return (random !== GenerateRandomNumber1to20No1) ? random: GenerateRandomNumber1to20No2(); 

  ///////////HERE'S ONE PLACE WHERE RECURSION IS AN ISSUE, I BELIEVE //////////////

        }

 var GenerateRandomNumber1to20No2 = GenerateRandomNumber1to20No2(); 
$('.GenerateRandomNumber1to20No2').html(GenerateRandomNumber1to20No2);
```

**This generates 2 different numbers less than the previous 2 numbers:**

```
function GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo1() {
    var min = 2, max = GenerateRandomNumber1to20No1-1;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + 1;   
    return random;

}

 var GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo1= GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo1(); 
$('.GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo1').html(GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo1);

function GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo2() {
    var min = 2, max = (GenerateRandomNumber1to20No2 - 1);
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;   
  return (random !== GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo1) ? random: GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo2();

}    
///////////HERE'S ANOTHER PLACE WHERE RECURSION IS AN ISSUE, I BELIEVE //////////////


var GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo2 = GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo2(); 
$('.GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo2').html(GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo2);
```

I use these variables to replace elements that have classes that correspond with their respective variables.

```
<span class = "GenerateRandomNumber1to20nNo2"></span>
<span class = "GenerateRandomNumber1to20nNo2"></span>
<span class = "GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo1"></span>
<span class = "GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo2"></span>
```

For example, `<span class = "GenerateRandomNumber1to20nNo2"></span>` gets replaced with the number that was generated for the variable `GenerateRandomNumber1to20nNo2`.

Sometimes the code works fine: the variables generate and the elements are replaced with those variables. Other times, the variables don't populate and I get an error that looks like this:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo2
```

I've been informed that I'm getting this error because I use "tail recursion" but I'm having trouble applying my research on "tail recursion" to my code. I indicated the places in the code where I believe recursion is an issue.

If someone could give me advice using my specific code, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo2() {
  var min = 2, max = (GenerateRandomNumber1to20No2 - 1);
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;   
  return (random !== GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo1)// <=== HERE
    ? random
    : GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo2();
}
```

Imagine a case where you have gotten two random numbers: 2 and 3.
Now, you're trying to roll random numbers less than 2 and 3, while still using 2 as the lowest number.

You're getting lost in these functions for a few reasons:

- You are overwriting functions with values that the functions return... so your functions turn into values. That becomes very hard to follow.
- You have 4 functions that basically do the same thing, but test different cases, which makes that part hard to reason about, because it's easy to squint and forget which one you're looking at(and are they still functions, or are they values at the point at which you look at them)
- You have some edge-cases that are logically possible, which you aren't testing for (which is why you're hitting infinite-recursion, and why you would hit an infinite loop, as well)

I'll update this, shortly with an example refactor.

```
function randomBetween (min, max) {
  var ceiling = max + 1;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (ceiling - min)) + min;
}

function randomBetweenAndExcluding (min, max, excluding) {
  var random;
  do {
    random = randomBetween(min, max);
  } while(random === excluding);
  return random;
}

var random1High = randomBetween(2, 20);
var random1Low = randomBetween(1, random1High - 1);
var random2High = randomBetweenAndExcluding(2, 20, random1High);
var random2Low = randomBetweenAndExcluding(1, random2High - 1, random1Low);

function addText (selector, text) {
  const el = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (el) { el.textContent = text; }
}

addText(".GenerateRandomNumber1to20nNo1", random1High);
addText(".GenerateRandomNumber1to20nNo2", random2High);
addText(".GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo1", random1Low);
addText(".GenerateRandomNumber1to20lessthanNo2", random2Low);
// PS you have a copy-paste error in your HTML classes, too
// the names are too long, and too similar, and already confused
// because of the overwriting functions with vars
```

In the case of this code, it's perfectly acceptable for `random1High` and `random2Low` to be the same number. If that was not acceptable, you would be opening yourself up to another infinite-loop checkmate if the numbers rolled were `2, 1, 3`.
If that's unacceptable, then you need to run the first two numbers as random between 3 and 20, so there's still room for 1 and 2, on the bottom, and make the exclude function a little fancier.

Hopefully, it's easier to see the moving pieces, here.

If you wanted to keep using recursion, like before (a function calling itself, from inside itself), you could define the second function like

```
function randomBetweenAndExcluding (min, max, exclude) {
  var random = randomBetween(min, max);
  return random === exclude
    ? randomBetweenAndExcluding(min, max, exclude)
    : random;
}
```

I generally prefer recursion. One downside to recursion is that it's possible to "blow your stack" / hit a "stack overflow" (same thing) in valid code, if you call too many functions inside of too many functions before returning (usually somewhere between tens and hundreds of thousands of calls, without returning, but still). So in the case of infinite recursion, eventually the browser throws an error.
The downside to an infinite `while` loop is that your browser and the page lock up, the loop never stops running, and eventually, maybe, your browser will pop something up and say "Gee; this sure has been running a long time; it looks like the page died, would you like to kill it?".

Comment: This is so helpful so far - thank you! I running to meeting right now but I will sort through this in depth tomorrow & accept your answer. I wrote myself a reminder. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to figure out...thank you, thank you, thank you!  One question: If I want to generate more than two numbers that unique, how can I expand to multiple exclusions? Essentially, I want these 2 lines `function randomBetweenAndExcluding (min, max, excluding)` & `} while(random === excluding);` to say `function randomBetweenAndExcluding (min, max, [multiple possible exclusion, not sure how many])` & `} while(random === [Anyone of these exclusions);`

Comment: @RB if all of the browsers are "evergreen" (support ES2016+), or you use a polyfill for Array methods (like the CoreJS polyfill that Babel uses), then you can use `if(exclusions.includes(random))` if you make it an array, instead of a value. If you can't support `includes`, you can use `exclusions.indexOf(random) < 0`, or write a function that takes a value and an array, and returns whether or not the value is in the array, whether you loop or use recursion, or use other methods like `exclusions.every(exclude => exclude !== random)`.